# Completely disable Google Analytics at sites.google.com

Tags: google, google-analytics, google-sites

I don't have Google Analytics account and don't want to use it on my site at sites.google.com, but nevertheless Ghostery shows that Google uses their own Google Analytics.

Is it possible? Or is it Google's price for providing sites.google.com?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't exactly the price for providing sites.google.com. This is the way that Google is able to collect some demographic and analytical data for the control panel. Even if you don't use analytics it is embedded within sites.google.com and can't be removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no possibility to remove Analytics tracking code from sites.google.com. It's not "your website" and you have no power on some additional scripts like Google Analytics.

But you can protect yourself, that your sessions will be not tracked by Google. Please check such plugins/solutions like:

https://tools.google.com/dlpage/gaoptout
or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-opt-out/fllaojicojecljbmefodhfapmkghcbnh

This is official Google plugin. I think that it is the best solution for you - no matter what, your data will be not recorded.tracked.